# How geoserver calculates Native Bounding Box from Oracle Layer?

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

I need to know, how geoserver calculates Native Bounding Box & Lat/Lon Bounding Box. I am publishing a polygon layer from oracle spatial.

In my case:

Table Records: 7679477

Native Bounding Box:

-201,637,684,178.654, -467,517,603,494.693, 
13,539,194.2440532, 17,742,292.9649778

Above calculated BBOX covers a wide area, and table consists data only for a state.

I am not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: if you query Oracle directly what bounding box does it give for your data? most likely problem is that the index is not upto date.

Answer (score 3):

GeoServer uses the top of the spatial index to quickly compute a rough bounding box by default, but you can go in the store configuration and disable the "Estimated extends" flag, this will make it compute the bbox going row by row.

Mind, with a few million rows that will take minutes, and the GeoServer UI will be locked down during all that time, all you will be able to do is wait, or restart GeoServer if you decide you cannot wait any longer.